Understanding Dennett's Philosophy of Mind
Daniel Dennett was a reductionist; he argued that the mind is entirely physical and can be reduced to the physical world.  In one his lectures, he spoke about the colors on the American flag and argued that subjective experience of red (redness) doesn't exist objectively, only subjectively.
I find this argument problematic and incompatible with reductionism.
If the subjective experience of the color red (a mental phenomenon) is actually a physical phenomenon, the interaction of light, eyes, brain and so on, then it must exist in space and time. Why? Because everything physical exists in space and time, including light, brain, eyes and human body. That's what being physical means.
If the subjective experience of the color red is equal to the interaction of light, eyes and brain, then it is completely objective and must exist in the physical world because light, eyes and brain also exist in the physical world.
So, if we say that the subjective experience of red exists only subjectively, and not objectively, that goes against reductionism. Reductionism says that subjectivity must be reduced to objectivity.
I'm not sure what am I missing.  Can you help me understand how Dennett's philosophy of mind address his own example about experiencing colors?

We are all watching the movie. Is it real? Does it exist? You can argue about it, but you cannot know with confidence.

Suppose I lay out fifty-eight rocks before you, and I’ve grouped them in twenty-nine pairs. Does your experience of the evenness of the rock collection’s cardinality exist in the physical world? How about if I add one more rock; does your experience of the new cardinality’s primeness exist in the physical world?

Under physicalism, subjective experiences are physical phenomena only in extension, in intension, i.e. the way we happen to mean them, they need not be. For example, rainbows are objective optical phenomena, but experiences of them as flamboyant bridges leading to pots of gold are subjective. Similarly, Superman is Clark Kent in extension, but not in Lois Lane's intension.

First, Dennett might better be called an material eliminativist. From WP:

The most common versions are eliminativism about propositional attitudes, as expressed by Paul and Patricia Churchland, and eliminativism about qualia (subjective interpretations about particular instances of subjective experience), as expressed by Daniel Dennett, Georges Rey, and Jacy Reese Anthis.

You say:

If the subjective experience of the color red (a mental phenomenon) is actually a physical phenomenon, the interaction of light, eyes, brain and so on, then it must exist in space and time. Why? Because everything physical exists in space and time, including light, brain, eyes and human body. That's what being physical means.

Mental representations do not exist spatiotemporally in the third person; only the media that carry them do. This is "if a tree falls in a forest, does it make a sound?" territory. According to a typical argument, there are atmospheric disturbances, but the brain is somehow connected to constructing and providing subjective qualia that are supplied by auditory perception. There is physical sound and experiential sound, and you can have one without the other. A completely deaf person is incapable of having auditory perceptions, and a schizophrenic who has auditory hallucinations has auditory perceptions and where no physical sound exists.
In reductionism, one often hears the language supervenience, dependence, and grounding (SEP), so it's important to understand a bit about the terminology. From the article:

The core idea of supervenience is captured by the slogan, “there cannot be an A-difference without a B-difference.” It is important to notice the word ‘cannot’. Supervenience claims do not merely say that it just so happens that there is no A-difference without a B-difference; they say that there cannot be one. A-properties supervene on B-properties if and only if a difference in A-properties requires a difference in B-properties—or, equivalently, if and only if exact similarity with respect to B-properties guarantees exact similarity with respect to A-properties.

This in no way implies that A and B are of the same thing. If A is objective and physical and B is subjective and mental, changes in A not only correlate to changes in B, but necessitate them in some sense. There is no claim inherent to the idea that the mental reduces to the physical that says, the mental is in some way COMPOSED of the physical. And that's where your presumptions seem to lie. It sounds as if you believe that if an auditory experience starts with physical sound, and reduces to physical sound, it is composed in some sense of physical sound. That is not a view you can attribute to reduction.


Mental representations do not exist spatiotemporally in the third person; only the media that carry them do.

What does "carry them" mean? Mental representations must be physical, that's reductionism. Mind is the brain. Therefore, if brain exists in the objective world, so should the mind. Why? Because mind is nothing more than the brain and body. Nothing more.
Saying that redness exists subjectively, but not objectively seems to be to be incompatible with reductionism. It's saying that redness isn't in fact reducible to physical. If reductionism is true, redness must exist objectively

I'm by no means an expert and could be misunderstanding something. However, I have been studying Dennett's work for a while and can't really completely grasp his point in this aspect of his philosophy.

Why should redness exist subjectively? Because subjetive experience of red is EM waves of certain wavelength exciting optical cones in the eye. These are converted to the optical signals which go to the back of the brain to be processed and interpreted. That's all we have in materialist toolbox. This is subjective experience of red. Since all these phenomena are objective, so should redness be since redness is exactly that. There is nothing more to it.

If one claims there is, he is rejecting reductionism. We can then talk about strong emergence or some non-materialist theory of consciousness.

The mind is not the brain. The mind, in some way, reduces to the brain. That's a very important distinction. The mind is mental, and the brain is physical, and these are NOT the same. The question is, how do they relate because they are NOT the same. What exactly that relationship is a central preoccupation of philosophers. Descartes posited substance dualism. Chalmers backs property dualism. Dennett at his peak advocated eliminativism borrowing from Ryle's notion of Cartesian theater...

In fact, many philosophers reject mental causation or mental representation "
Why should redness exist subjectively?" Presumably to function as a control system, according to some. Red, for instance, through an evolutionary lens is a way to advertise strength and danger. The question of why is redness red is Chalmer's hard problem of consciousness. The SEP article on supervenience explains why the mind not the brain

Saying that the mind isn't the brain, isn't reductionism. We can talk non-reductive materialism. However, I find non-reductive materialism problematic as I think reductionism is true. Liquid water is just molecules of water arranged and interacting in a specific way. There is nothing more to it. That's what liquid aggregate state is. Therefore, liquid aggregate state is reducible to molecular arrangments and interactions.

Consciousness should be reduced to physical, if one thinks that reductionism holds. If we take another organ in the body (not only the brain) like stomach, its function (digestion) reduces to what cells do and how do they interact. Cells make up a stomach. There is nothing more to it than cells interacting and arranging in a specific way. Is consciousness different than digestion in sense that it's not reducible to the physical (strong vs weak emergence)? Could be, but I'm really skeptical as it would need to be an exception in nature (as far as I'm aware).

"Is consciousness different than digestion in sense that it's not reducible to the physical (strong vs weak emergence)?  Consciousness is different than digestion because it's definition relies on indirect physical evidence, most importantly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neural_correlates_of_consciousness. Consciousness is not a physical phenomenon, and reduction simply means that there is an explanatory mechanism, not a spatiotemporal relationship.

@J D i think I got what Dan is talking about. If we take an example of red colour. Dan argues that red colour doesn't exist, what exists is the belief that red colour exists. This is what is encoded in our neurology and physiology. Brain misintreprets complex patterns of neural activity with: "there is something red out there", while it doesn't really exist at all. What exists is a belief about the colour, not the colour itself. There is no red on your retina, in the brain or in the outside world.

Consciousness in that sense is a brain's user illusion of itself. Brain doesn't need to know how it works to function in the world.  It can believe there is something red out there because that's practical. But, we shouldn't take it with a face value and literally believe it. Brain was made to survive, not to see the world how it actually is. Think you can trust your introspection as reliable? Optical illusions are a good example of how they seem very real to the brain, but how things seem, doesn't reflect reality.

In the context of user illusion, we can take the following example. When we move the document to the recyling bin on a computer, that process is represented as an icon moving on the screen. However, this isn't to be interpreted literally. It's just a representation of the complex process happening inside of the computer (removing something from the computer memory). The process of removing the document from the computer memory isn't actually moving the icon to the recycling bin. That's just representation, not what's actually going on.

What is actually going on isn't important from the user perspective to get things done. User doesn't need to understand how this process actually works to do this task on the computer. The same goes for the brain. It doesn't need to actually know what is going on inside. Believing there is a red out there is good enough for survival and functioning.

Well done. I would say that is a good interpretation. The mind constructs ideas and beliefs to survive, even if they aren't strictly speaking real or accurate.

Yes, I think Dennett's theory of consciousness is very good. It's concise, falsifiable, bridges the explanatory gap and it's reductionist.
